# json2csv not working as expected with mongoose aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following code

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const { Transform } = require('json2csv');
    const { UserModel } = require('./models/user.model');

    const users = UserModel.aggregate([
      {
        $sort: {
          _id: -1,
        },
      },
      {
        $limit: 100,
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
          fullName: 1,
          mobile: 1,
        },
      },
    ]).cursor().exec();

    const fields = ['fullName', 'mobile'];
    const opts = { fields };
    const transformOpts = { highWaterMark: 16384, encoding: 'utf-8' };

    // const input = fs.createReadStream('./public/users.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });

    const output = fs.createWriteStream('./public/data.csv', { encoding: 'utf8' });
    const json2csv = new Transform(opts, transformOpts);

    const processor = users.pipe(json2csv).pipe(output);
```

If I execute this query the data.csv file only contains

```
"fullName","mobile"
```

but if pipe from static json file i.e. `user.json` the `data.csv` contains all rows. What I am doing wrong? any idea?

Comment: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: save or download mongoose aggregate results to csv file using json2csv

Comment: So what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: following code save only column name with empty rows

Comment: here is opts output.
```{ fields: [ 'fullName', 'mobile' ] }```

Comment: @Md.RejaulKarim did you find a solution for this?